disnake.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired при запуске discord-бота на python
Я написал небольшой дискорд бот. Вот код
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot {bot.user} in ready to work!")

bot.run("тут токен")


Но при запуске вылезает такая ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\myBot\new.py", line 11, in <module>
    bot.run("тут мой токен")
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\myBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 1126, in run
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\myBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 1105, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\myBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 1067, in start
    await self.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\myBot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 992, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
disnake.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.


Подскажите пожалуйста, как её исправить?



Перейдите на офиц. сайт
Выберите вашего бота.
Перейдите во вкладку Bot







Ниже будет категория Privileged Gateway Intents







Включите их все (переведите ползунки)


